VBA Macro generates html files with illegal characters
I've created a macro in Excel 365, using VBA.
It's function is to loop through some e-mails stored in Outlook 365 and save each one to a .msg file and a .html file.
So far it is working fine, except the html files are being generated with illegal characters.
The html file itself is created correctly with UTF-8 encoding, as checked with visual studio code, but the meta tag shows:
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

Also, when a special character like "á" is present in the e-mail, it's saved instead, with a character like this "�"
I don't know if it's relevant, but my computer's language is set to "Portuguese (Brazil)"
I've tried:

Finding a way to change the command ".saveAs" encoding to UTF-8 or Unicode, but it seems to only exist for text files, not e-mails.
Save the the body of the e-mail to a database directly, without creating a html file, but I need images to be present in the same way showed in outlook, so it didn't work either.

Here is the relevant code used:
Sub loopEmail(ByVal emails As outlook.Items)
    
Dim email As Object
Dim qtdEmails As Integer: qtdEmails = 1

'Loops through each e-mail
Dim i As Integer
For i = emails.Count To 1 Step -1

    Set email = emails(i)
 
    'Verify if it's an email
    If TypeOf email Is outlook.MailItem Then
                    

        'Saves ".msg" file
        email.SaveAs "c:\test\email.msg", olMSGUnicode
        
        'Saves ".html" file
        email.SaveAs "c:\test\email.html", olHTML
          
                          
    End If
        
Next

Set email = Nothing

End Sub


Your VBA code save the body message in HTML correctly.
When you open your HTML with Visual Studio Code you have to change document encoding, on bottom right of VScode, from "UTF-8" to "Windows 1252".
Alternatively you can open your HTML with NotePad++

You are right, even though VS Code automatically opens the file with UTF-8 encoding, when I changed it to windows-1252 the illegal characters disappeared. Still the encoding needs to be changed to UTF-8, otherwise I can't use it on the website that I'm building. I've realised that my question wasn't clear enough, so I'm marking your answer as accepted. Thank you!
